# Reload self-made module

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Files:

File 1: metrobot.py
File 2: irc.py
File 3: cmd.py
```

MetroBot.py starts irc.py, irc.py makes a while loop which then uses cmd.py.
I try reloading the cmd module from irc.py. After i've reloaded it, the changes in cmd.py still won't take effect.

Reload code snippet:

```
if ":!reload" in self.buf:
  reload(sys.modules['cmd'])
```

I've also tried

```
reload(cmd)
```

None of the two works.

Anyone know what cause the reload to not work, or another simple way? This script is meant to be running at all times.

Comment: How are you running the code? Just inside Python interpreter or some other way? I'm assuming that metrobot imports irc and irc imports cmd?

Comment: @Martin Yes, that is correct. Just inside the Python interpreter and metrobot imports irc and irc imports cmd. functions inside cmd is running trough a while loop in irc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following three mini-scripts to test this and it works:

bot.py:

```
import irc

def start():
  irc.run()
```

irc.py:

```
import cmd, time

def run():
  while 1:
    print cmd.dothis()
    reload(cmd)
    time.sleep(1)
```

cmd.py:

```
def dothis():
  return 1
```

Now if you run bot.start() it will print "1" once a second and if I then edit cmd.py at some point to say `return 2` it prints "2".. Obviously I'm imagining this is a whole way simpler than whatever code you're having, but you'll need to post some samples to help us answer you better. Or try breaking your code down and testing the reload with a stripped down version of your code.